# Linking a sub form

Tags: ms-access-2010

I seem to have a strage problem regarding the linking of a sub form.  I have a series of sub form linked to a master form in which upon loading all seem to work fine except one. 
On this particular one, I have linked the master field (control) to a control on the sub form. Very strangly, the link seems to be fine and when you toggle between the tabs where the sub forms are everything also seems to be fine. Unfortunately, after exiting the master form and then re-entering, the new data no longer appears..  (the data in the underlying table however is still there)

Also to note..  Strangely, when I remove all the links between the master form and the sub form upon viewing the form in view mode, no records are shown! (I was expecting to see ALL the records in the underlying table)

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue when linking multiple sub forms to one master one trick that I find quite useful sometimes is instead of linking the sub form using the forms field control, I do the following. 
1. Remove all links between the sub form and the master form
2. Open the sub form in another windows and in te data tab select the table that it is linked to and instead of the table click the small icon on the right to open in query window
3. In the query editor select all the rows from the table and the select the particular column that u wan to link with the master and in the criteria for that define the path to the linked field in the master form u can use the builder for that it wil be something like forms!frmMaster.controlname and save and close the query and form
4. On the before update event of the sub form you'll need to write a small procedure to auto update the linked field with the master form field as it won't do it automatically like it did when it was linked
Something like 
Me.controlname.value =  forms!frmMaster.controlname

This should solve ur problem

Comment: Thank you very much Izzy. Your solution to me seems complex and a workaround. I will give it a try but really want to understand why I have this problem.  What I have noticed so far is that creating the form from scratch solves my problem but unfortunately doesnt help me understand what went wrong the first time...

Comment: Izzy, i just added an additional sentence to my issue above "Also to note...." which may help you better understand my issue...  Thanks.

Comment: I see that is very interesting. Can you confirm the following things. When you open the subform seperately does it show you all the items? If so then it looks to be an issue with the master form. If not then i would examine the subform to see if the data table that it is linked to is correct. 

A way to quickly check would be to delete the form and its links and  recreate the entire sub-form and link it again to the master. See if that helps.

Comment: Yes, opening the subform by itself shows everything.  I recreated the Whole subform and now it works fine but i would still like to understand what happened.

Comment: I think it's a bug with access that corrupts the forms.  I used to get an error that asked me to save the form every time even when no changes where made it's very peculiar and I've noticed it happens when u have more than 2 sub forms usually